# WindowsXP - Script to Identify and kill a hung browser

Tags: windows-xp

I am completely new to Windows. I setup an automation framework on a windows XP box. The browsers brought up by the automation process at times hang and there is no way to recover except killing the browser window. What is a good programmatic solution to this, or a DOS script that can be used to accomplish the same?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about that, but on a side note, apparently google chrome tabs are implemented as separate processes (not threads).  See http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be easy to script.  But you can get the window handle using [GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515(VS.85).aspx) and then call the function [IsHungAppWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633526(v=VS.85).aspx).  It would be an easy program to write in c# or vb.net

Answer (score 1):

Try monitoring the browser thread state using VBScript.  Here's an example directly from MSDN:

`Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`
`strComputer = "."`
`Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")`
`Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")`
`For Each objProcess in colProcesses`
`objDictionary.Add objProcess.ProcessID, objProcess.Name`
`Next`
`Set colThreads = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Thread")`
`For Each objThread in colThreads`
`intProcessID = CInt(objThread.ProcessHandle)`
`strProcessName = objDictionary.Item(intProcessID)`
`Wscript.Echo strProcessName & VbTab & objThread.ProcessHandle & VbTab & objThread.Handle & VbTab & objThread.ThreadState`
`Next`